# How to make syntax highlighter work in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntaxhighlighter

I want to syntax highlighter work in textarea
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of open source libraries that does the job..

One I remember is http://codemirror.net/.. Another I googled - http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/

Soruce of knowledge : Some basic googling skills :D

Comment: How to use it i am not able to figure out.. with the manuals

Comment: Which one you are talking about?